# Mostrar los valores de las tablas de la database dentro del html

Tags: javascript, nodejs

Estoy tratando de hacer una tabla en el `front-end` donde se muestren todos los valores de las tablas de la `database` correspondiente.

Hasta ahora, consigo sacar los valores y ordenarlos:

```
// SELECTOR
app.get('/list', function(req, res){
    pool.query('SELECT * FROM Pruebas', function(error, result){
        if (error) throw error;
        res.send(result)
    }
    );
});
```

Si después de esto entro en `localhost:5000/list` me aparece perfectamente todos los datos de la `database`:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El problema viene a la hora de intentar mostrar los resultados en el `index.html`, el cual lo tengo tal que así:

```
<!-- Esto en el head -->
<script src="app.js"></script>

<!-- Esto la tabla donde se deben insertar los valores -->
<div>
    <table id="tableData">

    <thead>
        <tr>
        </tr>
    </thead>

        <tbody class="tbody" >
        </tbody>

    </table>
</div>
```

Y lo siguiente es cómo insertarlo:

```
$(document).ready(() => {

$.ajax({
    url: "./list", 
    method: 'GET',
    success: function(response){
        if(response.rows.length > 0){
            for(let index = 0; index < response.rows.length; index++) {
                var newRow = $("<tr>");
                var cols = "";
                var nam = '';
                var ape = '';
                var sap = '';
                cols += '<td> '+ response.rows[index].nam +'</td>';
                cols += '<td> '+ response.rows[index].ape +'</td>';
                cols += '<td> '+ response.rows[index].sap+'</td>';                
                newRow.append(cols);
                $("#tableData .tbody").append(newRow);
            }  

        }
    }
})
})
```

Pero siempre me salta el mismo error en el navegador:

```
Uncaught TypeError: response.rows is undefined
    success http://localhost:5000/app.js:7
```

Creía que era un comando válido, pero al parecer lo toma como variable. ¿Hay alguna forma de hacerlo?

Comment: El error dice `response.rows is undefined`. Hiciste un `console.log(response)` para ver en consola lo que te devuelve el servidor?

Comment: Si,  y me devuelve un `array` con los valores de la tabla de la  `database`

Comment: Podrías añadirlo en la publicación?